# CentOS Hostname Change

Tags: centos6, hostname, oracle-xe

I'm using CentOS 6.5 where I successfully install Oracle XE. I want to change my Initial Hostname 'NAFD.WS' to something else. Will this affect Oracle Xe installation? If yes, what's the work around aside from reinstalling the Oracle Xe.

Thanks for your time dear SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your question is addressed here: http://minhtech.com/oracle/oracle-11g-xe-hostname-change/

Basically:

> Edit both the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files at $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/listener.ora and $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora. In the files, replace instances of the old hostname with the new hostname. Finally, log into root and force a reload:

```
$ su -
$ /etc/init.d/oracle-xe force-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of database functionality, it shouldn't matter.  I haven't installed XE in a long time, so, I'm not sure if there's an Oracle inventory, like there is w/ SE and EE.  If so, that would be broken, as the hostname is written into the inventory, and there's no supported way to update that.  That would imply you can't apply any patches, but, with XE, there aren't any made available anyhow.

If you were running RAC, you'd need to wipe and re-configure CRS, update local and remote listener configs, etc.

But, for XE, I think you'll be fine.

As always, if you care about the data in the database, be sure to take a backup before you proceed.

-Mark

Comment: Thanks for sharing Mark. I need to change the Hostname because when I try to ping my intranet Hostname NAFD.ws..it's pinging the Web Domain which is not related to us.